# Chave duplicada no mysql

Tags: mysql

Estou no terceiro bimestre de banco de dados e começamos a utilizar o insert em nosso banco porem me deparei com o erro

> "Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-aa4_a".

Existe uma função que possa resolver esse problema ou meu código esta incorreto ? segue ele a baixo.

```
-- drop database `chapelao`; -- caso eu não use o alter table  devo dropar a tabela
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `chapelao`;

use `chapelao`;

create table if not exists empresa(
    idempresa int auto_increment not null,
    cnpj varchar (45) not null,
    primary key (idempresa)
)Engine = InnoDB;


create table if not exists clientes(
    idclientes int auto_increment not null,
    rg varchar (45) not null,
    cpf varchar (45) not null,
    datadenascimento date not null,
    empresaid int not null,
    primary key (idclientes)
)Engine = InnoDB;

create table if not exists colaboradoras (
    idcolaboradora int auto_increment not null,
    nome varchar (45) not null,
    idade int not null,
    balao bool not null,
    rg varchar (45) not null,
    cpf varchar (45) not null,
    empresaid int not null,
    primary key (idcolaboradora)
)Engine = InnoDB;

alter table colaboradoras 
    add constraint fk_empresa_colaboradoras
        foreign key (empresaid)
        references empresa (idempresa)
        on delete no action
        on update no action;

alter table clientes 
    add constraint fk_empresa_clientes
        foreign key (empresaid)
        references empresa (idempresa)
        on delete no action
        on update no action;

insert into empresa (idempresa ,cnpj) values (null ,"08812216904");
insert into colaboradoras (idcolaboradora, nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values (null,"Taiana","19",1,"15011","15022",1);
insert into colaboradoras (idcolaboradora, nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values (null,"Debora","25",0,"15012","15023",1);
insert into colaboradoras (idcolaboradora, nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values (null,"Veronica","30",0,"15013","15024",1);
insert into colaboradoras (idcolaboradora, nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values (null,"Aline","22",0,"15014","150245",1);
insert into colaboradoras (idcolaboradora, nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values (null,"Luciana","23",1,"15015","15026",1);
insert into colaboradoras (idcolaboradora, nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values (null,"Carol","24",0,"15016","15027",1);
insert into colaboradoras (idcolaboradora, nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values (null,"Thalya","18",1,"15017","15028",1);
insert into colaboradoras (idcolaboradora, nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values (null,"Julinha","20",0,"15018","15029",1);
insert into colaboradoras (idcolaboradora, nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values (null,"Maria","25",1,"15019","150210",1);
insert into colaboradoras (idcolaboradora, nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values (null,"Polyanna","35",1,"150110","150212",1);
insert into colaboradoras (idcolaboradora, nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values (null,"Giovana","20",0,"150111","150213",1);
```

Comment: Executei o seu script e aqui não ocorreu o erro; eu sugiro que você : Drop o banco e execute novamente o script, instrução por instrução; Espero ter ajudado;

Comment: @Bacco sua solução foi eficaz obrigado

Comment: @LucianoSilva mesmo dando drop no database o erro continuava na linha 6 porem acredito ter resolvido o problema com a dica do Bacco

Answer (score 1):

Em uma breve pesquisa detectei que, o funcionamento de `INSERT` do MySQL é semelhando ao do PostgreSQL: quando há um `ID` específicado, o banco não atualiza o número registro inserido, diante isto, ao inserir registros informando a `PK` você deve informar também o `ID` que está sendo inserido.
Caso não queira se preocupar com `ID` remova o mesmo do `INSERT`.

Ficaria assim:

```
insert into colaboradoras (nome, idade, balao, rg, cpf, empresaid) values ("Taiana","19",1,"15011","15022",1);
```

Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp